# How to load file into mysql DB on a shared hosting platform?

Tags: php, mysql, load

A process running on my machine collects data from various websites and stores it in the local mysql db. Same data is exported using SELECT INTO OUTFILE and FTPed to the shared host every few hours. My hosting provider doesn't allow LOAD DATA INFILE to be executed on the shared host? What are my other options for automated/scheduled load to MYSQL db on my shared host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an excellent solution on this [webpage](http://chrisjohnson.blogsite.org/php-and-mysql-data-import-performance/).

Comment: Page does not exist

Comment: Link broken. Avoid this type of answer, at least give a summary of the solution

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of different solutions actually. You could export the data as INSERT statements and import that SQL file on the server, or import your current outfile dumps using a PHP script instead of using LOAD DATA INFILE, or create a webservice that allows you to update the data instead of your current dump/FTP/import scenario.

Comment: I don't want to do it one row at a time using INSERT. My shared hosting doesn't allow LOAD DATA INFILE within PHP script.