# php script to execute sql statements inside a dump file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, exec

I have a php script that is supposed to execute several mysql statements, everything works if there are no comments /* */  and no breaklines...

Could you please help me add this functionality, also ignore  `--` comments

```
<?
$sqlFileToExecute = 'mysql_dump.sql';
$hostname          = 'localhost';
$db_user           = 'root';
$db_password      = '';
$database_name    = 'db_';
$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
if (!$link) {
  die ("error connecting MySQL");
}

mysql_select_db($database_name, $link) or die ("wrong DB");
$f = fopen($sqlFileToExecute,"r+");
$sqlFile = fread($f, filesize($sqlFileToExecute));

$sqlArray = explode(';',$sqlFile);
foreach ($sqlArray as $stmt) {

 //THIS SEEMS NOT TO WORK 
 if (strlen($stmt)>3 && substr(ltrim($stmt),0,2)!='/*') {
    $result = mysql_query($stmt);
    if (!$result) {
      $sqlErrorCode = mysql_errno();
      $sqlErrorText = mysql_error();
      $sqlStmt = $stmt;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if ($sqlErrorCode == 0) {
  echo "SETUP COMPLETED ;)";
} else {
  echo "FAIL!<br/>";
  echo "Error code: $sqlErrorCode<br/>";
  echo "Error text: $sqlErrorText<br/>";
  echo "Statement:<br/> $sqlStmt<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Before finish read this question, I strongly suggest to dismiss `mysql_*` calls, because are deprecated. Use `PDO` instend or `mysqli`

Comment: looks like your processing an SQL dump file. in that case just load it all together http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712910/how-to-load-file-into-mysql-db-on-a-shared-hosting-platform

Comment: You need to replace stuff like `$sqlArray = explode(';',$sqlFile);` with a full fledged SQL parser. It's by no means a trivial task—I suggest you just find a third-party one. (Whatever, comments are ignored automatically by MySQL!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need to run it this manner:

You can also use

```
$mysql -pxxx -u username db_name -vvv < sourcefile.sql >/tmp/outfile.log
```

Enable verbose mode to check the stats, else you can omit -vvv option

OR

```
mysql > source "sourcefile.sql"
```

You can see more options [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html)

Comment: suppose I can not have direct access to server mysql console, so fastest way to do it is executing php script

Comment: what I am doing is uploading to the server (only ftp access) this script and the file .sql that contains the sql statements. Then as I know the user and database available (I want to create a table or something) I execute the php script and then I am able to use those created tables, now the problem yields in linebraks and comments